# UISearchController SearchBar changes after click cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uisearchbar

I have `UISearchController` in my app:

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    }

    searchController.searchBar.frame = searchBarView.frame

    searchBarView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

The problem is that when I enter the `SearchBar` and then click the cancel button the search bar not back to the frame I define here(and stretched to full size screen):

```
searchController.searchBar.frame = searchBarView.frame
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having this problem too.